# Delete rows with continuous dates within date period in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to consolidate employer records who are continuously work for same department](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848024/trying-to-consolidate-employer-records-who-are-continuously-work-for-same-depart)

I am trying to consolidate employees records who have been continuously (*anything < 45 days*) enrolled with the specific department

**Note**: If the date diff (*between `emp_eff_to_date` and next row `emp_eff_from_date`*) is less than 45 days then it is considered as continuous

#### INPUT:

```
EMP_ID +      DEPT_ID +        EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE +      EMP_EFF_TO_DATE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
10       10001       8/1/2008              10/31/2009
10       10001       11/1/2009              2/25/2010
10       10001       2/26/2010              5/1/2011
10       10001       8/1/2011              10/30/2011
10       10001       12/1/2011             10/31/2012
10       10003       7/1/2007              10/31/2007
10       10004       9/27/2004              6/8/2006
10       10004       6/30/2006              6/29/2007
10       10007       6/25/2006              6/20/2007
10       10007       8/25/2007              5/25/2008
```

#### Output desired:

```
EMP_ID         DEPT_ID      EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE     EMP_EFF_TO_DATE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
10          10001        2008-08-01             2011-05-01
10          10001        2011-08-01             2012-10-31
10          10003        2007-07-01             2007-10-31
10          10004        2004-09-27             2007-06-29
10          10007        2006-06-25             2007-06-20
10          10007        2007-08-25             2007-06-29
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: And please don't shout. Your title should not be in ALL CAPS.

Comment: How do you decided what the next row is?

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a very similar thing recently, and my first thought was a Recursive table expression, which works, but may not be the best solution depending on the amount of data that is in your table.

It is not clear whether you want to actually delete the rows from the database, or just view the results as required based on the records as they currently are.

**SOLUTION 1** ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fac6/2))

This uses the CTE to just select the results. It will essentially find the next row where the from date is within 45 days of the current row's to date, and keep looping until there are no matches. Once done it finds the result for the latest result for each from date (MaxRecursion field), and excludes then all other rows that fall within the date range of that row.

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  *, [Recursion] = 0
    FROM    T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  T.EMP_ID,
            T.DEPT_ID,
            T.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE,
            T2.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE,
            T.[Recursion] + 1
    FROM    CTE T
            INNER JOIN T T2
                ON T.EMP_ID = T.EMP_ID
                AND T.DEPT_ID = T2.DEPT_ID
                AND T2.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE > T.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE
                AND T2.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE > T.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE
                AND T2.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE <= DATEADD(DAY, 45, T.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE)
), CTE2 AS
(   SELECT  *, 
            [MaxRecursion] = MAX(Recursion) OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_ID, DEPT_ID, EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE)
    FROM    CTE
)
SELECT  T.EMP_ID, 
        T.DEPT_ID, 
        T.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE, 
        T.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE
FROM    CTE2 T
WHERE   Recursion = MaxRecursion
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    CTE2 T2
            WHERE   T.EMP_ID = T2.EMP_ID
            AND     T.DEPT_ID = T2.DEPT_ID
            AND     T.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE < T2.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE
            AND     T.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE >= T2.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE
        )
ORDER BY EMP_ID, DEPT_ID, EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE, EMP_EFF_TO_DATE;
```

**SOLUTION 2** ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fac6/1))

This will actually update existing rows, and delete redundant rows, meaning you can just select from the table to get the desired results. If ofcourse you don't want to actually delete from the database you could just insert the data into a temp table and apply the same principle ([Example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fac6/4)). In my case this solution ran a lot faster than using a recursive CTE, because at each stage of the loop the query is dealing with less data, rather than more as with the recursive cte.

```
WHILE EXISTS
    (   SELECT  1
        FROM    T
                INNER JOIN T T2
                    ON T2.EMP_ID = T.EMP_ID
                    AND T2.DEPT_ID = T.DEPT_ID
                    AND T2.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE > T.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE 
                    AND T2.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE <= DATEADD(DAY, 45, T.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE)
    )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  T
        SET     EMP_EFF_TO_DATE = T2.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE
        FROM    T
                INNER JOIN 
                (   SELECT  *
                    FROM    T 
                ) T2
                    ON T2.EMP_ID = T.EMP_ID
                    AND T2.DEPT_ID = T.DEPT_ID
                    AND T2.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE > T.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE 
                    AND T2.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE <= DATEADD(DAY, 45, T.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE)

        DELETE  T
        FROM    T
        WHERE   EXISTS
                (   SELECT  1
                    FROM    T T2
                    WHERE   T2.EMP_ID = T.EMP_ID
                    AND     T2.DEPT_ID = T.DEPT_ID
                    AND     T2.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE < T.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE
                    AND     T2.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE BETWEEN T.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE AND T.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE
                )
    END;

SELECT  *
FROM    T
ORDER BY EMP_ID, DEPT_ID, EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE;
```

All of these solutions differ to your sample data in the last row which appears to be an error:

I think this row:

```
10          10007        2007-08-25             2007-06-29
```

should be:

```
10          10007        2007-08-25             2008-05-25
```

Comment: Quick SQL Fiddle tip - you can copy OP's sample data and paste it into the "Text to DDL" tool to have it generate the table definition and insert scripts for you (in this case, after you remove the "+" characters).  Here's your query running against a schema that I build by doing just that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e02e6/1.  Should save a bit of time.  Cheers!

Comment: Incredible. You have once again out done yourself @JakeFeasel.

Comment: Thanks on quick response ... mY question was framed in a wrong so its confusing i guess ..  If you check the output i have mentioned it eliminates the rows which has emp_eff_to_date and next row emp_eff_from_date which has date period less than 45 days and results first row emp_eff_from_date and emp_eff_to_date of row till it breaks the 45 days criteria

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the next row is according to the `emp_eff_from_date` field (sorted), here is a way to solve it:

```
WITH DATA 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    PARTITION BY EMP_ID 
                    ORDER BY EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE)rn 
         FROM   TEST) 
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   DATA t1 
       INNER JOIN DATA t2 
               ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1 
WHERE  Datediff(DAY, t1.EMP_EFF_TO_DATE, t2.EMP_EFF_FROM_DATE) <= 45
```

The full solution is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/092a2/9)
Let me know if it's not exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks on quick response ... mY question was framed in a wrong so its confusing i guess ..

Comment: Thanks on quick response ... mY question was framed in a wrong so its confusing i guess ..  If you check the output i have mentioned it eliminates the rows which has emp_eff_to_date and next row emp_eff_from_date which has date period less than 45 days and results first row emp_eff_from_date and emp_eff_to_date of row till it breaks the 45 days criteria